# I need a formula to add a row and paste data into the new row in the correct sorted order

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google form that someone can use to request a meeting.
These meetings can be for any date in the future and I would like them sorted by the correct date.
Currently I have one sheet 'Sheet1' that collects the data and one sheet 'Sorted' that sorts the data as it comes in with this formula =sort(Sheet1!A2:D, 2, TRUE,3,TRUE)
On 'Sorted' sheet I have added checkboxes for other users to mark that they have seen the request.

Trouble is - when a new request comes in and gets sorted, the checkbox stays constant and does not move with the previous request.  Therefore the checkboxes no longer correspond with the correct request.

I feel like what I need then, is when a new request comes in, it triggers the 'Sorted' sheet to insert a whole new row where the new request belongs.  That way by adding a whole new row the checkbox stays with the correct request.

Thanks